# Flash AS3: ENTER does not get detected, but CTRL+ENTER works fine

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

When my focus is inside the input text field, pressing `CTRL+ENTER` works but `ENTER` does not.

Pressing `Enter` when my focus is anywhere BUT the input text field works just fine..

My intention is to detect if `ENTER` key was pressed after the user fills out the field, but it seems to only work for  `CTRL+ENTER`

**ActionScript 3**:

```
// works:
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, enterHandler);

// ignored:
email.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, enterHandler);

function enterHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER ){
        email.text = 'Thanks!';
    }
}
```

`ENTER` results in *charCode* == 0, whereas `CTRL+ENTER` is *charCode* == 13

`email` was created using the Text tool and set to "Editable"

**Note**: I am testing in Chrome and Firefox running Flash v10

Comment: it works now.  sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'm assuming you're debugging your work in ADL (*Control > Test Movie > in Flash Professional*)?  the problem here is that the keyboard shortcuts have precedence over keyboard events and the enter key is the keyboard shortcut for *Control > Play* in the *Control* menu while you are testing your movie.

however, it's possible and very easy to disable the keyboard shortcuts while testing your movie.  when your movie is playing, goto ***Control > Disable Keyboard Shortcuts***.  now your keyboard event for the enter key will execute properly.

---

**[EDIT]**

oh, and you should use `event.keyCode` instead of `event.charCode`.

**[EDIT #2]**

ok, if you want Enter keyboard event to fire when your currently inside an input TextField, you simply have to add TextEvent listener to the TextField:

```
import flash.events.TextEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFieldType;

var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.border = true;
tf.multiline = true; //Must be set to true for the textField to accept enter key
tf.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
tf.width = 200;
tf.height = 20;

tf.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, keyboardReturnHandler);       

function keyboardReturnHandler(evt:TextEvent):void
    {
    if  (evt.text == "\n")
        {
        evt.preventDefault();
        trace("text field enter");
        }
    }

addChild(tf);
```

Comment: I was testing in the browser. I changed charCode to keyCode, thanks for the tip. I updated the original post to add that pressing `Enter` outside of the input box field seems to do the trick, it's only when I press `Enter` inside the text input field that it gets ignored.

Comment: Does this updated code work for you? I was not able to get it working.

Comment: oh, i see my mistake.  for this to work you have to set the textField to multiline = true;  i'll fix my code.

Comment: unfortunately, using \r doesn't seem to prevent the default event from happening.  i'm not sure why.  of interest, you could write the same thing like this: evt.text == String.fromCharCode(13) if you don't want to hardcode "\r".  anyway, glad you have it working.