# Detecting KeyBoard events inside NumericStepper

Tags: actionscript-3, numericstepper

I have a movie clip with 2 buttons (Ok and Cancel) and one Numeric Stepper.

If the user press enter key on the keyboard I want that "Ok" button function runs and if "BackSpace" is pressed "Cancel" function.

I have this code that detect when I press almost all the keys but not when I press "ENTER" or "BACKSPACE".

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyPressed);

function onKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{

 if (event.keyCode==Keyboard.ENTER) {
       okBtnFunction();
 }
 if (event.keyCode==Keyboard.DELETE) {
       cancelBtnFunction();
 }
}
```

I also tried with event.charCode.

Comment: read a this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462028/flash-as3-enter-does-not-get-detected-but-ctrlenter-works-fine

Comment: Thank you bitmapdata.com, I also find how to EventListener KeyboardEvent inside NumericStepper.

Answer (score 0):

Enter and Backspace keys aren't enable because of the flash shortcut, you can see it in this link:

[Flash AS3: ENTER does not get detected, but CTRL+ENTER works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462028/flash-as3-enter-does-not-get-detected-but-ctrlenter-works-fine)

If you try to get keyboard event inside NumericStepper you have to use:

```
Object(this).YOU_NUMERIC_STEPPER.textField.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyboard_handler);
```

Remember to use **textField** after numeric stepper name.